# DevOps Separate Output Files Based On Project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So in my DevOps I have multiple projects, and I am choosing to build two of the projects, so I'm passing the path to those two projects like so:
[image]

But the issue is that the pipeline is placing all the files for both projects under the `drop` folder. Instead I want it to be something like `drop/Project1`. How do I do that?

I already tried using `$(ProjectName)` for my build argument like so:
[image]

But it doesn't work, even though I have set the `<ProjectName>` attribute inside both my .csproj, it becomes like this:
[image]

Is there any other way to do it? Or any idea why my $(ProjectName) isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that you can build each project in a separate task with its own output path.
It is a limitation of dotnet itself, `dotnet build` command does not support dynamic/multiple output paths https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing. I just created a separate task for each project. So far that seemed to do the trick but kind of a pain having to configure the `outputpath` for each project.